# Get the element using its attribute?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this,

```
<select id="rid" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" name="rid">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

and i have this links that triggers an event,

```
<a href="#">Disable Option 1</a><br />
<a href="#">Disable Option 2</a><br />
<a href="#">Disable Option 3</a>
```

Now if I click `Disable Option 1`, this would disable `Option 1` from the selection dropdown. I'm thinking, by using the attribute `value`, I can specify what option to disable with regards to what link I will click but I am lost. How would I disable any option on the dropdown just using the `value` attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:**

> like for instance when clicking Disable Option 1, it will disable options 1, 4 and 5 and when I click Disable Option 2 it will disable options 2 and 3, somewhat like that.

Setup links like below,

```
<a href="#" data-val="1,4,5">Disable Option 1</a><br />
<a href="#" data-val="2,3">Disable Option 2</a><br />
<a href="#" data-val="3">Disable Option 3</a>
```

And change code like below,

```
$('a').click (function () {
    var thisVal = $(this).data('val')+'';
    $('#rid option').filter(function () {            
        return $.inArray(this.value, thisVal.split(',')) >= 0;
    }).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**DEMO:**  http://jsfiddle.net/vPhJc/1/

---

If you setup links like below,

```
<a href="#" data-val="1">Disable Option 1</a><br />
<a href="#" data-val="2">Disable Option 2</a><br />
<a href="#" data-val="3">Disable Option 3</a>
```

Then you can

```
$('a').click (function () {
    $('#rid option[value=' + $(this).data('val') + ']').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vPhJc/

Comment: can I also disable multiple selections, say if I click `Disable Option 1` it would not only disable `Option 1` but also other options?

Comment: @CHiRiLo What other options you want to disable?

Comment: like for instance when clicking `Disable Option 1`, it will disable options 1, 4 and 5 and when I click `Disable Option 2` it will disable options 2 and 3, somewhat like that.

Comment: This is great. I really learned something from what you gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">Disable Option <span>1</span></a><br />
<a href="#">Disable Option <span>2</span></a><br />
<a href="#">Disable Option <span>3</span></a>
```

**Code:**

```
$("a").click(function(){
   // if you want to enable previously disabled option then do this
   // $("#rid").find("option").removeAttr('disabled');

   $("#rid").find("option[value='"+$(this).find("span").html()+"']")
           .attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/66hyZ/14/

Comment: This is great. I originally wanted to have search on what id im going to disable. This gave me the idea. Thanks.

Comment: I also want to retain my `<a>` links without any additional attributes.

Comment: Cool. I am glad that it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery supports selectors that can check for attribute values like [`[name="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

why not give each link an id and then disable the option in the select box using the id value

Comment: Originally, that was what I did but I was forced to not put ids because of a conflict.